# The type or namespace name 'ObservableCollection' could not be found

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I am working with Entity Framework in asp.net c# framework 3.5
I have generated entity classes using poco generator template.
But I am getting following error:

> The type or namespace name `ObservableCollection` could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

FYI `System.Collections.ObjectModel` is also added in class.

What could be wrong? How to resolve it?

Comment: Have you checked if you're missing a assembly reference? The ObservableCollection class is in the *WindowsBase* assembly in .NET Framework version 3.5, and in the *System* assembly in version 4.0

Comment: I think in 3.5, the assembly is different

Comment: addind windowsbase reference solved the issue. Thanks dtb. But now next errors ... :(


Error 4 The type or namespace name 'ObjectSet' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: The [ObjectSet<T> class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412719.aspx) is in the *System.Data.Entity* assembly in .NET Framework version 4.0. It does not exist in version 3.5. See: [Working with ObjectSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee473442.aspx)

Comment: My Bad :(
So .. I can't use these entity classes in framework 3.5 - right? Since I need to build application in Framework 3.5,
Is there any alternate to generate classes that support framework 3.5, other than POCO entity generator?

Comment: It looks like you generated classes for .NET 4.0 that do not work with .NET 3.5. Try making the generator create classes for .NET 3.5, use a different generator or write your classes manually. Which generators exist sounds like a good question to ask at stackoverflow.com :-)

Comment: You should accept at least one answer which worked for you.

Comment: @JoeFox If there actually is an answer that helped him

Answer (score 18):

using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

Answer (score 17):

Add **WindowsBase** to your reference.

Comment: This answer is right. Observable Collection its avaliable in 3.5, but you must add WindowBase reference.

Comment: Also available in 3.0, but as in 3.5 a reference to WindowBase must be added. It's not available below 3.0 as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 2):

@Riz Please ensure that your project has a reference to System.Windows as it appears that ObservableColletion is contained in System.Collections.ObjectModel namespace which is in System.Windows in .Net 4.0 and System.Collection.ObjectModel in .Net 3.0 & 3.5. It wasn't available before that. In silverlight it can be found in System.Collections.ObjectModel.

Comment: Not exactly. The ObserableCollection class is invariably in the System.Collections.ObjectModel namespace. However, it is in different assemblies in different versions of .NET: in the *WindowsBase* assembly in 3.5 and in the *System* assembly in 4.0. In Silverlight, it's in the *System.Windows* assembly.

Comment: Yeah, that problem was solved after @dtb comment. Now problem is ObjectSet .. see comments above

Answer (score 1):

Make sure System.Data.Entity Dll is version 4... not 2. Looks like it exist only on .net framework 4.0

Answer (score -3):

I think ObservableCollection only exists in .NET 4.0.