# Hiding Entity Model classes from Presentation Layer

Tags: c#, entity-framework, architecture

I am developing web forms app in C# Framework 3.5

I want to build something like "Presentation > BLL > DAL > Entity Model" flow in my application.  But problem is this that, how will I use entity objects in Presentation layer?

Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using Entity Framework?

If so, use the POCO Generator instead of the default EntityObject's.

While the POCO's are generated from the database model, they are effectively loosely-coupled because you can change the implementation of your DAL while retaining the previously generated POCO's as your domain model.

I'd suggest moving the POCO's (and the associated T4 Template that the POCO generator creates) into different project that is referenced by the Presentation Layer, BLL and DAL.

EDIT:

The alternative (if the POCO generator isn't working in 3.5) is to manually create domain classes and use those in the interface to the DAL. It increases the effort, but I recommend NOT exposing EntityObjects outside of the DAL.

Comment: Thanks @Steve Morgan. 

Yes, Using Entity Framework

I am thinking on same lines. But I have noticed, POCO's generated classes are not working in Framework 3.5.

See this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6685448/the-type-or-namespace-name-observablecollection-could-not-be-found

What are alternates other than POCO ?

Comment: Is there a specific problem with the generated classes that could be fixed manually? You could modify the T4 template (as I've done for various reasons) to generate the classes that suit you best.

Comment: Ah, it's the ObservableCollection stuff which, IMHO, is a pain anyway. As I mentioned, you can modify the T4 template and remove the dependency.

Comment: Thanks Steve.  One error left .. On this line
<br/>
        `public ObjectResult<lead> GetLeads()<br/>
        {<br/>
            **return base.ExecuteFunction<lead>("GetLeads");**<br/>
        }<br/>`

Error is<br/>

<br/>
The type 'Proj.EntityModel.employee' cannot be used as type parameter 'TElement' in the generic type or method 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<TElement>(string, params System.Data.Objects.ObjectParameter[])'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'Proj.EntityModel.employee' to 'System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.IEntityWithChangeTracker'

Comment: Going to need some more info. Is Employee now an EntityObject, generated POCO or hand-crafted POCO. Might be a good idea to post a new question.

Comment: Posted separate quesiton http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6686514/cannot-be-used-as-type-parameter-telement-in-the-generic-type-or-method

Answer (score 1):

I would actually take the following approach:

Have the models (POCOs) for example in a project that is referenced only by your DAL and BLL. That will ensure that you can work with them in the DAL layer and apply the business logic to them in the BLL.

For the presentation layer I would create DTOs (Data Transfer Objects) which will be carrying only the data that you need for a specific scenario/entity. The translation between the DTOs and POCO, I would place in the BLL.

I can think of the following pros & cons to this approach:

**1) Pros**

-- Full separation between presentation and core layers (BLL, DAL). Your DTOs will be independent from the database (POCOs) which means that whatever changes you do to the database, you will only need to change that in the translations layer.

-- Stable BLL API
   -- Validation separation - you can implement validation on the DTOs for the presentation and on the POCOs for the BLL.

**2) Cons**

-- Translation rules for each POCO-to-DTO. This will inevitably add some complexity to your code, but I believe that it is a good payoff.
   -- Performance overhead. The translation and instantiation of DTOs and POCOs will add some overhead to your application. Depending on your requirments and machine capabilities you can decide whether this is a good payoff.

I also advise you to take a look at some mapping libraries that allow easy mapping/translation between different types of objects. In my opinion the best one is [ThisMember](http://nuget.org/List/Packages/ThisMember/0.7.0) both in simplicity and performance.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to put edm in data layer. Then have another common project having all the poco entity classes. You can use Protocol Buffer for .net to map those entity objects to your poco entities.

In bll you can make the adapter classes and that should be the only interface between presentation and dal. Bll should communicate with presentation layer using poco entities.