# Cannot be used as type parameter 'TElement' in the generic type or method

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am using Entity Model, C#, .NET Framework 3.5.
I have generated entity classes from [POCO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_CLR_Object), but it had issues on ObjectSet and CreateObjectSet which I fixed by replacing them with ObjectQuery and CreateQuery.

But I still have one issue in following code in `EntityGenerator.Context.cs`,

The code is

```
public ObjectResult<lead> GetLeads()
        {
            **return base.ExecuteFunction<lead>("GetLeads");**
        }
```

And the error is

> Proj.EntityModel.employee cannot be used as type parameter 'TElement'
>   in the generic type or method
>   'System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction(string,
>   params System.Data.Objects.ObjectParameter[])'. There is no implicit
>   reference conversion from 'Proj.EntityModel.employee' to
>   'System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.IEntityWithChangeTracker'.

What's this error? What's solution?

Comment: You need to post more of your code.  It's a conversion error, but without the surrounding code there's no way to tell what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you just need to make `employee` implement `IEntityWithChangeTracker`.

(I suspect you've cut and paste the wrong section of code though, given that the error talks about `employee` and your code talks about `lead`. I'd also encourage you to change your names so that they follow .NET naming conventions.)

Comment: How do I change names, these are table entities generated from database. Is there any way to automatically change them?

Comment: @Riz: I don't know, to be honest - I don't know how you're generating. I'd certainly *hope* there'd be some way of changing them though.