# 'ObservableCollection' could not be found even when using 'System.Collections.ObjectModel'

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

`System.Collections.ObjectModel` is included. Visual studio 2012 still says `Type or namespace name 'ObservableCollection' could not be found.`

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6685448/the-type-or-namespace-name-observablecollection-could-not-be-found)

Code:

```
class ObservableClass : ObservableCollection<OtherClass>
{
}
```

EDIT: This is .NET Framework 3.5 and is a console application

Comment: Which framework are you targeting ? 3.5, 4.x, Silverlight, WinRT, WinPhone... ?

Comment: This is a .NET 3.0+ type. I'm targeting .NET 4.0 in a test project and it's working fine. Check your project settings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're probably missing an assembly reference... depending on which framework you are targeting, this class might be found:

- in WindowsBase.dll (.NET 3.x)
- in System.dll (.NET 4.x)
- in System.Windows.dll (Silverlight/Windows Phone 7)
- in System.ObjectModel.dll (WinRT) (included in ".NET for Windows Store apps")

Comment: Adding a reference to WindowsBase.dll fixed the issue. Thanks!

Comment: how to add it. i am having same issue