# 'ObservableCollection' could not be found even when using 'System.Collections.ObjectModel' and referencing proper assemblies

Tags: c#, .net, collections, .net-assembly

This is just like the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12570902/observablecollection-could-not-be-found-even-when-using-system-collections-ob) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6685448/the-type-or-namespace-name-observablecollection-could-not-be-found). I am targeting .Net 4.5

I am using `using System.Collections.ObjectModel;`

I also have references to:

- WindowsBase.dll
- System.dll
- System.Windows.dll

However I am unable to find the ObservableCollection. Any ideas on what I can do to resolve this?

Edit: Cleaned and rebuilt solution, still a no go.

Comment: Try to clean and rebuild your solution.

Comment: What framework are you targetting?

Comment: @xtnd8 cleaned and rebuilt, no go sadly.

Comment: @douglasg14b start to define type using its namespace (`System.Collections.ObjectModel.`...). Will IntelliSense dropdown list of available types?

Comment: @xtnd8 Yes, intillesense drops down a list of Types, ObservableCollection is in that list. That does allow me to use it, thanks. Not sure about the underlying cause, but that does resolve the problem. Feel free to add an answer, I appreciate the assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to start defining the type using its namespace:

```
System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<T> collection;
```

That should make sense.

Comment: As a last comment, after doing that I can now create a `ObservableCollection` by just typing it in as I would normally; `ObservableCollection<T> Collection`

Comment: @douglasg14b If typing the full namespace worked then that would indicate you haven't got the right `using` statement at the top of the code file using it.

Comment: That was my initial assumption, however as illogical as this is going to sound sound, I have changed nothing since posting this (other than cleaning and rebuilding) to ensure I could identify the exact cause when I found a solution. After typing out the full namespace, I can now just type 'ObservableCollection' and it is valid. I understand that's not "how it works", though take my word on it, this is exactly what happened.